# Question with horrible answers

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, voting, answer-quality, popularity

Following is a question with very special properties:

- **Importance**: Bad coding style will affect database security and potential hijacking
- **Relevance to beginners**: This is something that even beginners who write their first working code have to be aware off
- **Difficulty of knowing when you have it right**: Unless you are attacked, it's pretty difficult to know whether you actually secured against everything. Thus, it is difficult (especially for beginners) to know which answer is correct

Because of these properties, a lot of "semi amateurs", who know some things, but not sufficiently enough, have given answers they deem correct. However, most of them are horribly wrong. **But**, since those who ask or google the question do not know this, they will upvote any answer that "sounds correct" for them and delivers working code.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

For example, look at [Matt Sheppard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60442#60442). It has many upvotes, but also a negative comment that actually shows the flaws which has a lot upvotes as well.

I believe this is very dangerous and should be adressed somehow - at least brought into the attention of viewers.

The solution of protecting the answer (to anyone below 10 rep) is not really useful, since - as I explained - most of the bad answers come from semi amateurs, who are well above that threshold.

Perhaps there should be another protection level, or a big red warning.

Comment: Comments are the "read the small print" part of the answer, ignore at your own risk.

Comment: The comment was added **3 years later**. Partly the problem is also that this is not an interesting question for those that way above "semi amateurs" - they only see these questions because they snowballed in reputation and then realize what horrible answers have been given.

Comment: 30 answers (not counting deleted ones), oh my. [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168): "feature like this would make it _technically harder_ for me to post an answer. Imagine I am willing to add 20th answer to some question, that would mean I have to pass through checking 19 prior answers before posting my own, go figure..."

Comment: If the PHP community is willing, I can lock the mentioned question as a reference question, and they can coalesce all of the good information into the canonical answer (the accepted one).

This would make the top answer Community Wiki.

That said, it appears to me that Matt Shepard corrected the information in his answer later, in response to the comments.

Comment: While a step in the right direction, his edits are by far not sufficient. It should be a big fat "DO NOT DO". Rather he has "Do this, but it will not be supported in the future. Btw, here are other things you can do". Also, his answer is not the only terrible answer with positive reputation there, I just picked it because it was an extreme case.

Comment: That one specific answer can also simply be reordered to put the correct bits first and the obsolete bits last.  No major wording or meaning change would be needed.  Then it becomes just *old*, not bad.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sounds good. Whenever I find this very important question (normally through review) it is always in a worse condition. So many useless answers, misleading information, terrible practices. The one by Matt is one of the better ones actually...

Comment: **Any and all answers** that promote or even show **anything** that has even a slight chance to result in SQL injection should be **deleted immediately and permanently.**

Comment: It's useful for people to know that this used to be the best solution PHP had, and why it was bad, and why parameters are better, and that it should only be used if your PHP < 5.0 or your MySQL < 4.1 (I may be remembering those wrong, but whatever the right numbers are), and only during the period it takes to upgrade, and only with critical (e.g., money-related) features disabled until the upgrade is finished, and so on. I think the answer should be edited to make the legacy-ness clear, but it shouldn't be deleted, or downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: see also: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers)

Comment: This is how Skynet will be born, some guy will take one piece of eight of an answer with high up votes from SO, without reading high up voted comment .. and that will be the end of us

Answer (score 14):

I don't think there is an easy way to remove the attention from the answer - you can downvote but when there are already 100+ upvotes it won't make a massive difference.

What you should probably do:

- upvote the best answer
- downvote the wrong answer - it will hopefully work in the end
- upvote the comments that point out the mistakes made in the answer
- add a short and neutral sentence at the top of the answer to direct readers to the comment section, like in [this other broken answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283722/829571) - if your comment is too assertive it may start an edit war
- award a bounty to the best answer to help it stand out

Comment: +1 for mentioning adding a neutral warning at the top.

Answer (score 4):

(Edit: I propose an attack below, but I'm leaving my original answer up here because I think it's worth keeping.)

I'm not sure it's a tractable problem. Mass effect, patience and statistics are the strongest weapon we have.

1. A person never knows everything about a problem domain.
2. An individual is competent to judge neither [their own competence nor the competence of others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).
3. The individual who has the most significant impact on the reputation of an answer-giver for a single answer is the person asking the question. (A person who, by nature, is bound to have a gap in their understanding of the problem and be biased towards a [satisficing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisficing) rather than actually *good* answer.)

The best we can hope for, on average, is

1. The community knows more than any individual.
2. The community, on average, will use votes (up and down) responsibly, which means good answers will *eventually* outweigh satisficing, but incomplete answers.
3. Many questions will disappear into time and only really affect a tiny fraction of the community: the asker, the answerer, and one or two hapless others.

## Suggestion

Now, for really well-understood subjects like SQL, one solution might be to grant individuals with tag badges the ability to red-flag answers like this. Just throwing the idea out there, what if:

1. A "red-flag" is defined as an answer that is both often-seen and suboptimal in a subtle, but dangerous way. In other words, an antipattern.
2. Individuals with gold badges in a tag used for the question would be able to "red-flag" an answer.
3. Five such flag-votes would result in the question having a marker attached to it.
4. I would go on to suggest that such an answer be automatically converted to CW once flagged.

The value of such a marker instead of outright deleting the answer or downvoting it into oblivion is that, as an antipattern, another naïve person is likely to attempt the same approach/answer again.

Comment: "The community, on average, will use votes (up and down) responsibly, which means good answers will eventually outweigh satisficing, but incomplete answers." - Well, here we have a clear case where this process failed and a `mysql_real_escape_string`-answer has a score of 600 with a 1:20 up/downvote ratio. This question is about what we should do when this community selection process fails, which you don't address. Also, your first 3 points seem to be of little relevance, as it's easy (for anyone who knows what they're doing) to tell when an answer is factually incorrect or harmful.

Comment: @l4mpi Significantly edited; however, let me point some things out. 1. The community can still miss things, as in your example case. That doesn't nullify the average beneficial effect. 2. I addressed the community selection process in my update, although making a democratic process more republican (as it were) introduces its own set of flaws. 3. My first three points are relevant because it points out how difficult it is for the community to identify, as you say, someone who knows what they are doing.