# Answering an old question with duplicate answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answer-quality, popularity

This question ([In a SELECT statement(MS SQL) how do you trim a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179625/in-a-select-statementms-sql-how-do-you-trim-a-string/)) was asked 6 years ago, has 120K+ views and received many answers.

It's been inactive for over a year, and before that, 3 years and before that another 3 years or so.

This user has posted an answer to it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29538380/3000179), which is a duplicate (minus the `FROM` clause in the query and the ugly formatting) of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/179637/3000179 - both are which in the same thread.

**My question** is how should I respond? The answer *isn't* wrong, but it's a duplicate and obvious give-me-rep try (IMO).

Would a custom flag of "duplicate of answer 179637" suffice, or would it be better to just leave it? <sup>Am I overreacting?</sup>

Comment: related: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers)

Comment: Thanks @gnat - flagging now

Comment: consider bringing to mod attention that question is rather popular (120K+ views). It also wouldn't hurt if your flag message refers to your question here

Comment: Ah, already flagged it `:/`

Comment: no problem, I cast my own flag over there with these details

Comment: You'll see this happen as a strategy for new users to siphon upvotes from high scoring, highly viewed questions on the coat-tails of the existing high scoring answers. Drive-by upvotes happen all the way down the list of answers on popular questions, including bad answers or copied answers.  You are _not_ overreacting.

Comment: _"duplicate of answer 3000179"_ Actually, you want the _first_ number in the share URL to get the answer id. The second number is _your user id_ and, if you look, is the same for both links you posted. It's used to keep track of link shares for a couple of badges. Just a note for the future. :)

Comment: Ah how embarrassing. Thanks @Kendra. I've edited my question to reflect this