# Question with many, many answers that are just localization differences

Tags: discussion, answers, popularity

[Go to Matching Brace in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio)

This question has a couple of highly-upvoted answers, then many, many answers that are just variations of

> In *[some language]* keyboard, the shortcut is Ctrl + *[some key]*

Is it appropriate to flag the question to clean up the answers? On one hand, they do answer the question, and on the other hand, they seem to be more appropriate as comments/edits on the accepted answer.

Comment: Consider looking into making a [meta-tag:canonical] question and answer.

Comment: English, French, German, Spanish, Portuguese, Italian, Danish, Turkish, Dutch, Slovenian, Brazilian Portuguese, Swedish, Swiss French and Hungarian. Plus Norwegian and Icelandic in the comments. At least the community is thorough.

Comment: Thorough? 17 out of [6,909](http://www.linguisticsociety.org/content/how-many-languages-are-there-world) languages. We still have some work to do, it seems.

Comment: It's not how many languages there are, it's how many keyboards layouts there are.

Comment: @Aaroninus which could be even worse... In Canada, with 2 languages already covered elsewhere (English, French), we still have three new keyboard layouts (Canadian english, Canadian French, and Canadian multilingual-standard)

Comment: A community wiki answer seems appropriate to me... followed by a deletion/cleanup of all the answers that are less than 10 words long

Comment: There appears to be an [answer already to show how to determine the shortcut currently in use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6309463/1756702). Enumerating per keyboard seems unnecessary, but all such comments and answers could be combined into a single community wiki answer.

Comment: Feels like a case for [documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865).

Comment: @Patrice Switzerland has its own layouts for German, French and Italian as well. And then there's the Apple version of every keyboard too.

Comment: @Patrice - While some languages will get multiple keyboard layouts, it's doubtful that every language has at least one. Languages currently at risk for extinction probably don't have their out keyboard layout.

Comment: Although this doesn't affect the op's question, there are also non-standard layouts too #happycolemakuser

Comment: [Solution](https://www.sonderdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/output_QYDvRx.gif)

Comment: I've seen the same thing regarding questions about installing software on unix type systems.  Every *nix has it's own package manager, so I've seen answers that are all variations on "run `sudo <insert package manger here> <package name>`".

Comment: Is it possible that some of the answers were contributed in the spirit of "Here's an answer you _some-language-centric_ git" or satire? I had to laugh when I saw the macro with animated demo.

Comment: see also: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers)

Answer (score 4):

I think all of these answers are useful to the variety of users of Stack Exchange, so I'd recommend keeping them. The OP didn't specify the locale anyway.