# User posting systematically late (copy-pasted) answers in popular posts

Tags: discussion, reputation, popularity, late-answers, abuse

A user has a habit of posting late answers in popular questions that are copy-pasted (somewhat rephrased) from the top answer(s). These posts add no extra info/value to the OP.

[Deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty/32289099#32289099)
[copy-paste 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289024/4230591)
[copy-paste 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289443/4230591)
[copy-paste 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290074/4230591)
[copy-paste 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists/32289201#32289201)
[copy-paste 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980808/i-have-an-input-that-appends-to-a-list-how-do-i-print-out-the-last-list-itemth/32289464#32289464)
[copy-paste 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary/32288804#32288804)
[copy-paste 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32288804/4230591)

I flagged some of the posts (and they are deleted), but there seem to be quite a few of them, so I wonder what action should I take in cases where a user does this intentionally in order to game system.

Obviously a -2 from a downvote would make no difference to a +50 answer. Also, I don't feel like downvoting more than 2 of the user's posts lest I trigger vote-reversal.

Also, I think that this trick is followed by other late answerers. Further investigation of popular posts with late answers might be needed.

Comment: Custom flag one of them and explain the situation.

Comment: @RobertLongson The problem is, that i think i found a second user doing the exact same thing, a few minutes ago. This is not a single offender.

Comment: @RobertLongson What do you mean 12? I got like 100 per day. You ve been checking the Meta profile :P

Comment: @RobertLongson If this isnt a widespread tactic then you are right; flagging should suffice. Otherwise a more generalized solution will be needed.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no *generalized solution* to plagiarism, apart from detecting and flagging it, which we already do. We could apply harsher penalties (say, 6 months suspension after two plagiarized posts) but the moderation team does not seem too keen to do that.

Comment: @gnat Uhm.. not exactly. This is a case of a user doing this systematically. Not just answers from **random users** that I found.

Comment: the answer you look for is in [dupe target of that question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255572/839601) - "Cast a custom moderator flag, explaining the problem..." (it works even for single answer, and when there's a pattern of repeated abuse you simply add that to the flag message)

Comment: @gnat You might be right. I mostly wanted to keep this open in case a mod could provide info regarding how often this type of abuse happens, or tools they use about it, or extra things we should do. I could simply create a separate post for that if i do indeed find many others using this abuse.

Comment: @gnat Never mind i changed my mind. I prefer to post it here instead of having flags declined ([flagged](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36286667/4230591) as copy of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7302987/4230591), flag declined). My beautiful flag ratio was damaged!!!

Comment: yeah handling of non-trivial flags is unfortunately somewhat... capricious

Comment: From where is the second example copypasta'd?  Also, all of these are trivial AF answers on questions that are very basic.  Each of the questions has tons of answers to it, most of which are variations of each other.  Simple answers to a question are often very similar to each other.  You can't single out an individual one among them as being a copy.

Comment: Wait.. why aren't you flagging http://stackoverflow.com/a/7302987/1228 as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/a/61918/1228?  The second was answered in 2008 with `len()`, whereas the first comes along in '11 and just puts `len()` into a line of code?  The original only has 28 upvotes, whereas the DUPE has 244!  This is an outrage!

Comment: @Will _"You can't single out an individual one among them as being a copy"_ - Actually sometimes you can. Simply look at the dates. Answers posted 3 years apart are very different from answers posted 5 minutes apart. The first case should be removed if they add nothing of use.

Comment: @Will Regarding the posts you link, the flag would most likely get declined. I do agree though that the dupe shouldn't be posted and simply the first answer should be (maybe) edited instead.

Comment: *"Answers posted 3 years apart are very different from answers posted 5 minutes apart."* You can't make that blanket statement.  Look, adding trivial answers 6 years after the fact that are trivially different from another trivial answer is bad.  We agree on that.  Downvote it, leave a comment saying that the answer doesn't add anything to what already exists, vote to delete it, great.  Fine.  But you cannot claim that the user is copying answers, and flags saying so will be dismissed.  Save this type of flag for more complex answers which are trivially different from another.

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure that the answers are actually plagiarism before flagging.  If you are absolutely sure, and have the source to prove it, flag for moderator attention and explain what you observe: that this user is plagiarizing answers from other Stack Overflow posts without attribution.

When I flag for plagiarism, my message usually looks something like:

> Plagiarized from [link] without attribution

You can also comment on the post to explain to the user that what they are doing are wrong:

> It looks like this answer has been copied from [link]. Can you edit your post and give attribution to the original author? Plagiarism isn't really welcomed on Stack Overflow, and it's always nice to give credit where credit is due.