# Cleaning up popular question with multiple duplicate answers added long after the first one

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, popularity

Following question [#pragma mark in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017316/pragma-mark-in-swift) has multiple duplicate (as in copied content) answers that were added long after the first few ones. They don't add any new information nor are useful in any other way. Since question is two years old some of the duplicates also collected up votes rewarding *bad behavior*.

**What to do?**

1. Downwote
2. Flag as NAA? - I am worried that flags would be rejected
3. Flag for moderator attention
4. Do nothing

To illustrate

[image]

Comment: Questionable answers if you ask me. It seems more like a change log than a real Q/A set.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Part of the problem is because at time question was asked feature was not yet implemented, otherwise question could be closed as RTFM one. Even now it is useful Q/A. It is just that there is too much noise there made by people trying to score some cheap rep points.

Comment: As the content is plagiarized in multiple answers, one custom(Mod) flag is sufficient.

Comment: @Tushar Flag the question itself or one of the answers?

Comment: That doesn't matter. Just describe the case.

Comment: related: [Lots of duplicate answers on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271158/839601). At 120K views this question possibly deserves [Atwood's cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773). Or at the very least protection from passers by

Comment: I flagged it for mod attention. So I'll see how it goes from there...

Comment: *Flag as NAA? - I am worried that flags would be rejected* And you should.  If they are a duplicate answers then they are answers.  We have down votes and delete votes for bad quality answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver they are answers like you say. Problem with down voting and deleting is that those actions are beyond my reach - I cannot delete answers. And for those with multiple up votes, my single down vote will not go as far...

Comment: This is what delete votes are for. It just sucks that there is a 20k barrier before you get the privilege of being able to cast delete votes on answers.

Comment: over two dozen answers, and while there are several really nice ones, about half are the sort of me too garbage that tends to blight high visibility questions.  What a mess!

Comment: If there is actual plagiarism (copying without attribution) then flag for a moderator and explain, including a pointer to the source material. With such short answers (examples provided in this question) and not *exact* copies, it is hard to say the newer answers are actually plagiarism and not just very similarly written original content.

Comment: "duplicate (as in copied content)" -- No, accusing someone of plagiarism is a lot more serious than saying the answer duplicates the substance of another answer. I do not see verbatim copying here, just a serious misunderstanding on the answerers' part about how to answer. As Makyen and psubsee2003 have said, if you really had copied content, you could flag it.

Comment: @Frank When I said duplicate content people misunderstood that I am complaining about multiple answers. So while it is hard to say that any of the answers I am talking about were literally copy pasted, they are really repeating same thing with slightly different words and they are added months after "originals" were added. So it is not matter of accident when simple question is answered using similar words by multiple people at basically same time frame. Regardless of what it is called, it is about adding answers that don't bring anything new and valuable.

Comment: Ok, I agree. Just beware that "copied content" implies that someone actually took the action of copying (part of plagiarism), while "duplicate" is a much weaker accusation (basically just of redundancy).

Comment: This question was in desperate need of protection, so I did that. I also voted to delete some of the low quality answers I could. From my experience in viewing other popular questions, duplicate content *usually* ends up deleted, down-voting and flagging to describe the situation is the best you could do, I guess (and this meta post too).

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Thank you for cleanup assistance :)

Answer (score 24):

### Recipe for abusing the system by late-parrot answers:

- Find old popular post (usually trivial question with trivial answers).
- Read top answers.
- Post similar answer, that adds nothing new of value.
- Grab pieces from several existing answers (not just one or two), to reduce deletion risk.
- Wait as, slowly but steadily, you get rep.
- Amass 1000 rep from such fraudulent behavior without ever losing it. (when old posts are deleted, [the rep is not removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers#comment381630_255572))

---

### Moderately effective solutions:

**Downvote**
Not very effective. I lost 70 rep in 2 days downvoting such answers.

- You will lose huge amounts of rep.
- Risk of vote reversal if you accidentally downvote a user that [systematically posts late-parrot answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331754/user-posting-systematically-late-copy-pasted-answers-in-popular-posts).
- The parrot doesn't care. An answer with +10/0 score instead of +10/-1 means 100 vs 98 rep. Why would he care?
- Moderately effective against 0 scored questions, since it will make them less visible if negative... **temporarily**; the drive-by "upvote-everything-to-get-the-badge" will see to it. Also, if a post reaches the negative score  20k'ers can vote to delete ([thanks @JimFasarakis-Hilliard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335548/cleaning-up-popular-question-with-multiple-duplicate-answers-added-long-after-th/335622?noredirect=1#comment401137_335622)).

**Flag as NAA?**
Since mods aren't familiar with *all* technologies, they will probably decline any cases that aren't clear-cut.

**Flag for moderator attention**
Currently [i m guessing that this is your only option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255572/4230591):

> Answers that merely parrot information that someone has already provided earlier (for some significant amount of time earlier) in lesser detail don't add any value.
>
> Cast a custom moderator flag, explaining the problem ("This answer is a duplicate of an answer already posted two years ago").

but do it [sparingly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers#comment380245_255572):

> Flag things as you see them. You don't have any moral obligation to comb the site looking for every one of these things.

I strongly disagree with the above, but this is what a mod said.

**Do nothing**
This would allow parrots to keep dumping trash and waste precious time of viewers. We don't want that.

**Comment**
You'll get serial downvotes; funny to see his downvotes reverted, but not funny if you happen to annoy a knowledgeable parrot.

---

### More drastic measures

The late-parrot-farmers use some tricks in order to avoid deletion of their useless content. They sometimes modify slightly an example that already exists. They use a slightly different, yet useless approach (e.g. in Python: using `__len__` instead of `len()`).

**A change in policy** is needed against late-parrots' answers that farm the system.

Magnificent birds, but they need to be put back in their cage. We don't want to clean up their mess.

[image]

Comment: Down-voting is really important, if a post reaches the negative score realm 20k'ers can vote to delete (and some of them are already deleted!). Also, automatic up-vote for giant parrot with a cowboy hat riding a tractor.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Didn't know that, added in answer. Although it does indeed make downvoting more useful, when a post has +10 it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard downvoting is useful as long as many users do downvote these answers, or at least enough of them do not upvote them... which is normally not the case

Comment: Yup, highly upvoted duplicate answers will most likely stay unless dealt by a moderator. +9 and +8 answers are managable with a meta-effect, I believe. We've already deleted 5 low scored in the question, so, it's a start :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Downvote

You're certainly welcome to if you think the answers aren't useful.

> Flag as NAA? - I am worried that flags would be rejected

As you should be.  The answers aren't not an answer, and so don't merit flagging as Not An Answer.

> Flag for moderator attention

On what grounds?  That you don't think the answers aren't useful?  That's not grounds for moderator intervention.  It is the responsibility of the community to indicate answers as not being useful thorough votes.

> Do nothing

Considering you know that the answer isn't useful, you certainly shouldn't refrain from downvoting, so no.

Comment: It is not about usefulness but copied content added months after original

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar you never mentioned "copied content".  If it is actually **plagiarism**, that changes the situation dramatically.  If it is just someone leaving a similar answer (even months later) or expanding an earlier answer (while providing attribution), that really doesn't count as "copied content" in the same sense.

Comment: I edited the question to illustrate what kind of answers I meant.

Comment: _"On what grounds?"_- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255572/4230591