# How to handle multiple duplicate and low quality answers on popular questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, quality-improvement, answer-quality, popularity

Popular questions often have a lot of answers. Rarely each of these answers presents a good, unique solution to the problem (also, that could indicate that the question is too broad). In most cases many of these answers are low quality and offer the same (or very similar) solution.

Let's take a look at answers to the question [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/3853934):

- Some answers are effectively duplicates of others. [Danilo Colasso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682010/3853934), [Joe Lewis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18783123/3853934) and [kaizer1v's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26569856/3853934) offer the same solution as [pimvdb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364203/3853934) (i.e. "use the `filter()` method"). [Zirak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364204/3853934) offers the same solutions as [JaredPar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364184/3853934) and [pimvdb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364203/3853934).
- Some answers don't work at all (for example [aggaton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22943874/3853934)).
- Some answers (like [volumexxx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138786/3853934)) contain code that is long, ugly and slow.
- Some answers (like [Manu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27751551/3853934)) require an additional library to work, even though [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag excerpt says "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

How to handle such situations? These answers can't be deleted through Low Quality Posts review or by delete votes of trusted users, because they have positive score. One solution that comes to my mind is to post a Meta question with a request that a moderator deletes these answers. Another option is to create a new Q&A and close the old one as a duplicate. What do you think of these options? Is there any other better solution?

Note that I'm not asking specifically about answers on this question. I'm asking how to handle it generally.

Comment: Leave any necessary comments. It often encourages a delete, re-tweak, or others to ignore the post

Comment: @Drew That might be useful in some cases, but doesn't solve the problem. For example, I left a comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26569856/3853934). My comment currently has a score of 6, but nothing happened to that answer.

Comment: Who ever said these produce guaranteed results. In addition, we lack the resources to do much about it. As gnat is here, perhaps he can offer some ideas on that one. Granted, it is answer-side, but for 20k rep users that could delete such posts, they are not given adequate resources to do much (in the face of all the questions to delete)

Comment: 616K views. And it isn't even protected, no wonder that any passer by brought into there from google search is willing to pollute it with their infinite wisdom. And if amount of views like this doesn't deserve an  [Atwood's cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) then I don't know what does. There are less than 600 questions all time viewed that much

Comment: Downvote the answer(s)?

Comment: @JAL how many of them? There are 27 answers and 15-20 of them seem to deserve downvote. I wonder also what one could accomplish with downvote on an answer that sits at +10,+20 (at 600K views any mess dropped into the question has a good chance to get random upvotes "for effort")

Comment: Maybe we should be able to "flag as duplicate" on answers, in much the same way we can already do to questions. Such an action could result in that question being visible only to certain users. Then if a question attracts multiple answers that end up flagged as duplicates that question can be automatically protected

Comment: @DarrenH if an answer is an "exact duplicate" of another answer, usually you can mod flag explaining the situation and it will be deleted.

Comment: Protecting a question only locks out users with less than 10 rep. I only see one answer there that would've been prevented by protection, and it's a "please help" NAA, and it's already deleted.

Comment: Closely related: [Flag duplicate answers on the same question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266469) [Cleaning up popular question with multiple duplicate answers added long after the first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335548)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 if you look closer you'll find two more answers that would be prevented by protection. Their authors got >10 rep now but all of their rep is from these answers. "at 600K views any mess dropped into the question has a good chance to get random upvotes "for effort"

Comment: @gnat - I only found one user who got all their rep from their answer on that question and has no other activity. Given 32 total answers on that question, I don't think protection would be very effective for it. Protection seems mostly intended to prevent random passersby from dumping NAA/spam answers into popular questions. I agree that it's irritating when people add unoriginal, unhelpful answers, but the most you can realistically do about it is downvote (and maybe delete vote if it's really garbage).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 please look at [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4268255/quincyaft?tab=topactivity) and [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2120115/volumexxx?tab=topactivity) - these are two (of 27 answers visible under 10K). I think that something like [forced review of prior answers](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168) could work better but protection is still better than nothing (worth noting 1 rep users differ from 10 rep in that they have nothing to loose from downvotes)

Comment: @gnat - Ah, I only spotted one of those. That question does have a lot of negatively-received answers, so I went ahead and protected it. Maybe it'll help a little.

Comment: I think we need a "clean up and consolidate" phase. That is handled delicately, without the presumption that if an answer is merged or removed as essentially a duplicate then the author has lost face. If an answer is erroneous, obviously it need to be removed, but be careful it unambiguously is - for example a lot of quite experienced programmers don't really understand the relation between "goto" and structured programming, and an answer that is in fact correct will attract some downvotes. There are other issues like that.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean you might be interested in this discussion at MSE: [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773)

Comment: related: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255571/839601)