# Why was this answer (which was definitely an answer) deleted?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, deleted-answers

[Link to the post for reference (non-10K)](//stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/14153210)

So this post was apparently deleted. *Why*, though? According to the comments on it, it was deleted as "Not an Answer". The problem is that it clearly attempts to answer the question, and while it might not have been presented well, it *definitely* was an attempt to answer the question and should not have been deleted as such.

So what was it? Robots in LQP? Or something else?

Comment: It's a copy of an existing answer. Perhaps it was deleted for plagiarism.

Comment: But it doesn't show me the other answers :(

Comment: It does if you click on the question title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is a (partial) copy-paste of a much older answer on the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33898705

Its presence does not make the information easier to find, understand, or use: it simply clutters the page, and [actually it makes things worse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336750/3853934). Removing it was absolutely the correct action, and I'm glad that the reviewers were sufficiently conscientious in this case to realize that.

Comment: The real question is why it took _six_ people to vote to delete.

Comment: I would guess because it's not obvious it's a copied answer just by looking at the review queue, you would need to click through to the question which a lot of people don't do.

Comment: I'm talking about the fact that [six users are listed as deleters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfqMl.png).

Comment: @JoshCaswell because it only got one *real* delete vote: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13990278

Comment: It's good to know that a number of reviewers _did_ click through and looked for context!

Comment: @JonClements, ah, thanks for that link! I should have thought to look at the original review itself.