# Should you raise a flag when a question is several years old and still getting new answers?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

I have noticed a couple of questions recently pop up on SO, that are several years old, in this case 6 years old, the answer given very recently is irrelevant to the question.

Should if any flags be raised?

The question specifically is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer)

With the question being 6 years old, I can't see how any answer now is valid as jQuery has evolved dramatically since then. More to the point, the answerer mentions using underscore.

Comment: **question with 120K views**... wonder how many deleted answers are there (such questions tend to attract garbage answers from web searches). Somewhat related: [Cleaning up popular question with multiple duplicate answers added long after the first one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335548/839601)

Comment: Side note: question says "JavaScript or JQuery" - so pretty much any JS library usage is fine there. I also strongly suspect that you use "valid" in the post as "answers I like" rather than "works correctly". If you see answers that are wrong - downvote - but so far top answers on linked post look correct (maybe not the latest possible, but so what?)

Comment: @gnat 2, one of which was self-deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't flag posts because you think the answer is wrong, outdated, fails to adequately answer the question, or otherwise not useful.  Those are all reasons to *downvote* a post.

If a post actually merits flagging, say because it's not actually an answer at all, it's offensive, spam, etc., then by all means, flag it, regardless of how old it is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.