# Why was my NAA flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I flagged this post: [loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx/46070418#46070418) (meanwhile deleted) as NAA. It may look like an answer, but it is just a copy of another anwer plus the user saying that this helped. I even added a comment telling what's going on, but the flag got disputed. Since I don't have any other means to appeal I am asking here.

Comment: If you find plagiarism.. _mod flag it_ with a link to the source post/content and explain.. It wont be NAA IMO

Comment: @suraj: it's not really plagiarism, just a newbie who probably just wanted to say this answer from above worked for me.

Comment: Reviewers probably missed the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842051/1426539), being that the question has list of answers two pages long...

Comment: @gnat: looking at my flagging history I guess I know what NAA is.And as pointed out above, this doesn't seem to be a case of plagiarism. For me it's still a NAA case, maybe not so obvious on on the border but...

Comment: *disputed* means the community rejected the flag in a review queue. That means we'd have to track down each reviewer and ask them directly, we can't read minds I'm afraid. At best we can offer *our* opinion on the merits of your flag.

Comment: @jps: *maybe not so obvious on on the border*: then flag with a custom flag. A copied answer still looks like an answer.

Comment: looking at your flagging history I guess I have ~60x more helpful flags than you, so you better trust me that NAA isn't a good fit for this case

Comment: @gnat, you mean that it shouldn't be flagged at all, or that a NAA flag specifically wouldn't work because of this particular circumstances?

Comment: NAA flag specifically wouldn't work (more precisely you could have some of them work but that would be a pure luck because most of these flags are handled by not very experienced 2K users). Whether this specific case deserves custom moderator flag, hard to tell - I don't feel inclined to thoroughly study answers you asked about. Consider studying discussions tagged [meta-tag:plagiarism] to make your mind on that

Comment: I think that @jps is right when they say that it is not a case of plagiarism, but a clumsy "it worked for me too" comment. As in _"a commentary on another post, not an answer"_. But I agree that for reviewers it could be quite hard to get, as Martin pointed out, so a custom flag would be the way to go.

Comment: thanks for the comments everyone. I just asked this to get a better understanding of how things work and get the commuities opinion on such cases. I'm still learning a lot here everyday. The 'NAA'  answer has been deleted now. At least some people understand and agree that was not a so clear case. I often hesitate to use other flags as I had my own experience with them aging away and left unhandled and I also didn't want to accuse someone of plagiarism when it was just a "clumsy" comment (thanks yivi).

Comment: Maybe it is not entirely plagiarism ( wasnt trying to accuse ). But either way a custom flag or mod flag would have worked

Comment: oh I just noticed the question you ask about is 300K views. This is a well known pain, see [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255571/839601) and multiple discussions linked to it

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your flag was "disputed" because your peers (other members of the community working through the "Low Quality Posts" review queue) thought that answer "Looks OK".

You can see what happened [here in the review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17248967). Three people said "Looks OK", while only one said "Recommend Deletion". Three "Looks OK" votes was enough to mark your NAA flag as "disputed", and kick the post out of the queue.

Note that no moderator was ever involved here. Sometimes (ideally, most of the time), the community handles NAA and VLQ flags completely on their own. That's exactly what happened here. Had your peers agreed with you that the answer needed to be deleted, your NAA flag would have been automatically validated and marked "helpful", and the answer would have been deleted. Since they didn't think it should be deleted, your flag was marked "disputed" and the answer remained.

Had a moderator been involved here (and sometimes we do process NAA/VLQ flags, especially in situations where there are too many of them for the community to get through), then "disputed" would not have been an option. Moderators cannot dispute NAA or VLQ flags; all we can do is mark them "helpful" or "declined".

So...that's the literal answer to your question of why the flag was disputed.

Next follow-up question is <s>why are my peers so dumb</s> why did so many people say that answer "Looks OK". Well, the simplest explanation is that it looked to them like an answer to the question. Since all you see when reviewing is the answer itself, along with the question, it isn't unreasonable for them to have reached that conclusion. The answer presented a code snippet that was ostensibly relevant to the question, and such valid attempts to answer are not generally deleted.

Unfortunately, this was a bit of a special case, since the answer was merely a duplicate of an existing answer. Charitably, we'd say that it was an attempt to say "thank you", but more precisely, it was plagiarism, since it copied code presented by someone else without providing proper attribution. Either way you go, whether you deem the answer a rule violation or whether you just say it's noise, it needed to be deleted. The reviewers missed that.

The *only* clue there in the body of the answer itself that it was a bad answer was the "As suggested" phrase, but that's not a very strong clue. The reviewers would have had to open the question separately in another tab and read through *more than a page* of existing answers to correctly discern the problem with this answer.

You can blame the reviewers all day, but the fact of the matter is, they acted rather responsibly. Faced with uncertainty about the acceptability of the answer, they erred on the side of caution and chose to preserve it. That is really what we *want* people to do. Honestly, it's quite likely that, *had* a moderator been involved, they would have done the same thing—completely missing that the answer had been plagiarized from one of the other answers (particularly easily missed in this case, since [it is hidden on the second page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842051)).

In the future, when you see something like this, don't just flag it as "not an answer". Raise a custom flag, indicating it requires moderator attention. Something like:

> possible plagiarism of <link to other answer here>

(Note that this is not an accusation, just a request that a moderator investigate. If you feel uncomfortable making direct accusations of plagiarism, then this wording is perfectly acceptable and achieves the same result. If it's really clear-cut and you want to omit "possible", then I don't have a problem with that, either.)

Don't leave cases like this up to community reviewers, and don't leave moderators having to guess about it. We don't want to take the risk that something this serious is overlooked.

Also, *please, please, please* include a link to the answer/external resource you think it was plagiarized from. I sometimes get flags that say "plagiarized from another answer", which means I have to go read all 25 answers to the question to confirm (and justify my taking evasive action). That makes me sad, and wastes my time. You already did the legwork; please share its fruits with us!

Comment: Another possible wording is "copy-pasted from [...]". Still sounds a bit accusing to me, but at least it sticks to the verifiable facts.

Comment: "copy-pasted from ... without attribution" has exactly the same meaning as "plagiarized", so...whichever. :-)

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to write a thorough answer. This helps me to better understand the mechanisms on SO. Do I get that right, when I flag NAA or VLQ the post will just appear in the 'Triage' queue to be judged by some people? Wasn't aware of that! Good to know.

Comment: @jps not the Triage.. it goes into Low Quality Post queue..

Comment: thanks @suraj I see, it's a 2k+ queue, but seems to be quite similar. Guess I'll see the difference once I reached 2k

Comment: Triage is similar, but different. The system is actually pretty complicated. There's [a flowchart here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjvml.png), but don't worry about the details. The decisions you make in both queues should pretty much be the same. I don't pretend to understand the fine distinctions, either. @jps

Comment: For clarification, users can see comments on the answer though, correct? I was in the exact same scenario as the OP (users copy/pasted the answer to say "thanks") so I left a comment explaining the situation to the poster (but under the assumption that the reviewers would see it). I think this is more efficient than bothering a mod with a custom flag.

Comment: @C.Helling I have no idea if comments are shown in review or not (I think they are, except for audits), but you really *should* be flagging suspected plagiarism for moderator attention.

Comment: @CodyGray Is there any way to find out relevant review tasks based on the flag?

Comment: @Nisarg There is an easy way for moderators, but that button isn't available to regular users. I know it can be done, though, as people regularly do it on Meta. I've honestly never cared enough to go looking for a way. I'm guessing they just go through recent reviews looking for it.

Comment: @NisargShah completed review tasks for particular post can be discovered [via timeline or Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248286/165773)

Comment: @gnat Thanks a ton! I finally reached to [this](https://stackapps.com/a/4238) link - which let's me get the timeline link through Tampermonkey!

Comment: Good work Cody Gray.  I like your work and your style.  I'm glad you got voted into the moderator group.