# What about bad new answers to old questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, answer-quality, popularity

I have recently consulted a question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-create-a-directory-if-it-does-not-exist?rq=1) on Stack Overflow.

Most of the answers were from years ago, from people with a considerable reputation here, and they were of good quality, diverse answers. But some others were from last year, written by users that **literally** copied other people’s code, with worse explanations and even missing out parts of it or indenting it incorrectly (it was about Python, where indent matters), though they appear much higher in the ranking because they were published sooner.

I would like to know what tools does Stack Overflow have for this kind of answers. I think there is a moderator section that cares about 'new answers to old questions', but I am not sure if there is a flag for answers that are repetitive and add nothing, though make the user attention deviate from the important content.

*Can they be flagged? Would they be removed? Should not there be a mechanism to, if not delete, put them lower on the listing?*

**Edit**

Here is some information about the answers listed below the question. Please note the dates and the votes (I did not add the poster’s reputation, but that would also be interesting).

- #1st answer: 3059 votes, 7 nov 2008
- #2nd answer: 2 votes, 16 dec 2017
- #3rd answer: 0 votes, 16 dec 2017
- #4th anwer: 564 votes, 16 jan 2013

The first four answers follow the **exact** same approach, with different explanations, apart from the forth, which adds a multiple Python version support (which is pretty nice). Second and third answers have very little or no reputation, and neither do their users.

Also 2nd and 3rd were published the same day, so the sentiment is that the question showed up in 'hot' or 'featured' tabs and inexpert users attempting to help copied old approaches. I suggest some mechanism is established to prevent this.

Comment: This is a problem with all highly viewed questions. If the answer adds nothing I normally downvote, add a comment explaining the problems to discourage upvotes and vote to delete if possible. The question can be protected but that only prevents a subset of bad answers.

Comment: @MartinSmith but protection only prevents from under 10 reputation users, AFAIK, and some of those users have even around 300 reputation. I wonder if these might get deleted if flagged because I don’t see any flag category for that.

Comment: And I am asking how would I flag it if that is the correct way, since downvoting won’t actually remove the answer. It will at most bring it down the rank.

Comment: Down voting below 0 is a prerequisite for 20K users to cast a delete vote.

Comment: @MartinSmith could you expand a bit more on how that works in the answer box? :)

Comment: The question is protected, but it is not enough here.  Just flag it with a custom moderator flag and ask him to lock it.

Comment: I have seen a lot worse than in the example question.

Comment: @BhargavRao at over 1,5 million views this questions deserves [Atwood's cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) don't you think?

Comment: @gnat, it is just 4 answers short from the too many answers auto flag, (on which we usually cleanup). Alternatively, if you see any post that is similar to an older answer, just custom flag that post with "same as the answer here <link>", and we'll delete it.  (There has been one deleted answer on that because of a similar flag)

Comment: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255571) would be a better dupe; it actually has an answer from one of the most senior mods.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yea I was surprised by noticing how they marked a dup that had no answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the new answer is [actually an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552), has no [severe formatting or content issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122443), is neither abusive nor [promotional](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), it does not warrant a flag unless the poster [repeated one or more much older answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255572) almost verbatim OR the poster has added the same answer to multiple questions. Additionally, a steady stream of near-duplicate answers is a sign that the question may need to [be locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229).

In case the answers are ordered by score (the default), new answers are already somewhere at the bottom of the page. If they don't warrant flagging, but you feel they are not low enough, you'd downvote them. Once an answer reaches a certain score, high-reputation users will be able to delete it. Note that almost every major tag has an active community behind it, with plenty of users who care about post quality. You can speed up this process by drawing the problematic post to their attention (e.g. in chat).

You would help future readers by additionally pointing out the issues in comments. Chances are, the answerer will delete or improve their post.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but look at my edit from minutes ago. 2nd and 3rd answers in the rank were 0-2 votes, compared to 4th that was over 500. Also 4th was much more complete and genuine. If we go down the list this behaviour would very probably repeat (just click on the link and check it by yourself)

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde I see this when I select "active" ordering for answers. The default setting is "votes", in which case the answers are sorted by their scores.

Comment: You are right! I did not notice. However, I must say that that was the default for me when I opened the page. I don’t know if that is related with the question having been featured, but I certainly decided to post this question because of that. I am not sure whether or not the default tab is the vote sorting feature.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191496/260312)

Comment: Can we comment that an answer adds nothing new that wasn't already covered?

Comment: @usr2564301 I've done that. In that case, a downvote is 100% appropriate, too (adds nothing new -> "not useful")