# Deletion of original answer after its copy was deleted

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

I had posted an [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712598/832230) and then its self-identified [copy on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712700/832230). Both were deleted by a mod saying that *identical* answers are not allowed. I acknowledge that [*duplicate* answers are frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/), and I will leave debating this policy for another day.

For now I want to know why the mod deleted *both* my answers rather than just one.

I put in time and effort into writing what I consider is a useful answer.

**I would like for my original answer to be undeleted**, and for this to not happen again to anyone. I shouldn't have to repost my original answer.

Comment: Both your answer cover inspec.currentframe() wich is already covered in the others answers despite your disclaimer. (both questions have answers with examples or mentioning it)

Comment: _Maybe_ it's a good idea not to duplicate content in the first place... Especially considering the questions are rather old already, and seem to have plenty of (similar) answers, any way. You can't come come in here after (bluntly put) breaking the rules, to make demands.

Comment: Your first answer is the 8th answer on a question from 2009... There's already a mention of `currentframe` on there, albeit in the comments. I am on point.

Comment: This passive aggressive attitude isn't helping your cause, Acumenus.

Comment: Well, if you can edit your answer to explain why you would specifically use `inspect.currentframe().f_back` instead of one of the techniques in the other answers, I will consider undeletion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's fair. Regarding the answers using `inspect.stack()`, it's [way too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407119/python-inspect-stack-is-slow). Regarding the ones using `sys._getframe`, it's an internal *private* function due to the leading underscore, and so its use is implicitly discouraged. Lastly, as for an answer using `inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe(), 2)[1][3]`, it's unclear what `[1][3]` is doing.

Comment: Yep.  Put that in your answer on the original question (not the one George Stocker just marked as a duplicate).

Comment: see also: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255571/839601)

Comment: @RobertHarvey [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712700/832230). I acknowledge it would've helped me to do this yesterday.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please *always tailor your answer to the question you're answering*. Assuming the questions aren't duplicates, there's *something* unique that should be addressed in any reasonable answer - if that doesn't happen, it's a huge red flag (best-case: author didn't read the questions carefully; worst-case: spam).

The person best positioned to do this sort of work is the author of the answers - you. Asking moderators to figure out which answer out of several *isn't* blowing off the asker is too much: even if they have sufficient expertise in the subject matter, it's tedious, error-prone work that you could've easily done when posting.

Spend a minute re-reading the question(s) to ensure you understand the problem being solved, and then re-post your answer(s) - this time, tailored to address the specific problems being asked about. There's no penalty for doing this, and the results will be better for everyone involved.

Comment: The questions are effectively duplicates given the nature of their answers. It's not my fault if the answer was a duplicate even though it was tailored.

Comment: Additionally, considering the timestamps of the 2 answers, it's rather obvious the OP already had both questions in mind when writing the answer. (They're posted less than 7 minutes apart)

Comment: We generally try to leave one answer around; and delete the one the system flagged (or delete the one a user flagged); I can't speak to why both were deleted here.

Comment: @Acumenus with your reputation, you should be able to vote to close then instead of posting an answer that is a duplicate?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Noted. You're right, and I should've done that, but merely voting to close still leaves a question open for a long while, potentially forever, as the question may never accumulate sufficient votes to close it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's a good idea not to duplicate content in the first place.

Especially considering the questions are rather old already, and seem to have plenty of (similar) answers, any way.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113) already has some mentions of `currentframe`, so the added value of your answers is debatable.

If you find 2 questions that can be answered with the same answer, it's quite likely that they're duplicates. Consider close-voting one as a dupe of the other, then answer the dupe target.

---

Next time you disagree with a moderator's actions, you can also use a custom flag to ask for clarification. Flag one of your answers, or the question, explain what's wrong, and a moderator can respond.

Comment: There is a comment by 1313e from May 2019 covering the use of currentframe with f_back, but that is not an answer. That comment is easily overlooked. I myself overlooked it. As far as answers go (and not comments), my answer remains original.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard for the moderator to judge which answer to leave. While deleting both of them might not be the best decision ever, it is an option.

I would suggest flagging the post where **you think that your original answer should remain, is appropriate and tailored to the requests of the OP** for moderator attention, asking to undelete your answer.

I doubt, that if that one instance of an answer is worth keeping, this request would be ever denied. In such a way, **you would do the work** that you expect a moderator should do.