# Why was this late yet correct answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

The OP of the question [Prevent dotnet core 3.0 from building EXE by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491492/prevent-dotnet-core-3-0-from-building-exe-by-default) came back to the question a few months after asking it, and self-answered with what had worked from the comments received in the question, which seems appropriate given that the commenters didn't post an answer.

While the answer isn't of the best quality, the OP even appropriately referenced the users that helped give the answer. It doesn't even warrant a downvote in my opinion, but I think it's too much that it was deleted by a moderator. 10k link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59704181/

Screenshot for users below 10k:

> [image: deleted answer screenshot]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I just read that situation as well, flagged the answer asking _"Why was this answer deleted? It is an answer, by the OP, from the hints they got in comments"_. The answer requires editing (XML parsed as HTML), but it is a valid answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster I wasn't sure if I should raise a flag or ask in Meta first

Comment: I am curious, "with no explanation" - do you mean comment or custom text in "closed" plate? I guess it could simply be a reaction to some flags, will e.g. "closed because of flags" reason change anything?

Comment: @Sinatr Anything that would have made me understand the decision. A comment would have been enough

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto There is no reason to be unsure. If you can back up a claim with a good explanation, you have every reason to flag.

Comment: Related: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers)

Comment: This "answer" literally quotes two comments without providing any additional information.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica That may warrant a downvote (or editing), but not a binding deletion vote.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica "This "answer" literally quotes two comments without providing any additional information." That's fine as long as the comments fully answer the question and aren't yet contained in other answers. The effort is here that BrianM recognized that situation and converted them into an answer, which allows to vote on them.

Comment: And that is the reason why you should not post answers as comments. Put them in the answer box.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thank you for bringing this up.  I was still somewhat new to the question asking, and was totally confused on why my answer was deleted.  I recall even putting a comment on my question asking why it was deleted, and it looks like the comment was deleted as well.  I feel if a moderator is going to delete an answer they should put a comment explaining why they did it so that we can learn from it.

Comment: @BrianM Don't worry too much about it, it was a mistake, it's common for people to post answers that don't add any value and for moderators to delete them. The comment was deleted after this Q&A, since it was handled

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Sorry, I misread the situation when I was handling NAA flags. Thanks for bringing this up!

I've undeleted the answer again.

Comment: Thanks for owning up to it.