# Controversial audit post

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

In the Late Answers review queue I've come accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28130248) audit post. I was supposed to take action against it. The explanation in the comment says:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have
> sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post;
> instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the
> asker. - From Review

I'm not so sure it doesn't answer the question. The person got the same error, implemented a fix and shared it. I don't know whether this actually works or not, but that is not the point of that flag anyway.

The *real* problem seems to be that he assumed that the asker had a certain feature turned on in his IDE. I think the reasoning behind deleting his answer was that he didn't comment first to clarify that. However, in the review queue we are not all experts in these topics, and we are not supposed to be - I believe this is the reason why the Triage queue doesn't have a filter option. To my understanding, we are rating the *quality* of the posts, not their *usefullness* (as in 'do they work?').

I don't know the default settings of all IDEs for all project types. If his answer assumed it was the default setting or at least a commonly used one, it is a fair asumption. There are many highly rated answers with similar asumptions, like 'if you have your input on separate lines' or, which isn't even included in most posts, 'if you can use external libraries' (which is not obvious for every project).

I also don't know how specific the error is, maybe it can only occur if the checkbox is used. In this case there is no need to comment. Again, one more thing a reviewer can't know.

An other problem is, since it is an audit, comments are usually hidden. This means I cannot even check whether he has asked it, unless I open the question in a new tab (which would show me that the answer was deleted, defeating the purpose of audits).

Don't get me wrong, I understand why it was deleted and that it was probably the right choice made by someone with sufficient knowledge, I just doubt that it is a good audit post.

I'd appreciate if you could explain me how to detect these kinds of answers in audits and why they are suitable. After reading these posts ([Why are "Late Answers" reviewed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148088/why-are-late-answers-reviewed), [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work), [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)) I'm still not sure. The last post recommended to post here.

PS: I know that I'm supposed to skip the post if I'm unsure about what to do, but when I reviewed it (with the same reasoning) it seemed like a good post (with some small formatting issues, but still easy to understand).

Also, I forgot to mention that my review priviledges were suspended (after 2 failed audits, I didn't even know that was possible).

EDIT: I'd like to point out that this is not a clear duplicate of [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers). The answer is unique. It might be low quality, but from the comment it looks like it was flagged as NAA - which is part of why it is so problematic for me to understand the expected behaviour.

Comment: "*... unless I open the question in a new tab (which would show me that the answer was deleted, defeating the purpose of audits).*" That's what I used to think as well, but it turns out plenty of reviewers will click on the links as a matter of routine, and this is perfectly acceptable. I agree that it seems to defeat the purpose of audits, and I've not sure why that's normal practice.

Comment: @yivi no action is needed, it's a unique new answer.

Comment: @yivi I don't see the other answers when reviewing an answer. The post might show the amount of answers (I'm not sure). It also doesn't show whether the post has an accepted answer or not. I'd have to open it in a new tab, which I think is not good practice

Comment: I cannot include more details if the answer is about a topic I don't know much about. It stated that the error occurred becouse the user used a checkbox, and can be fixed by not using it. This seems logical to me. Also, if I understand your comment you don't agree with the reasoning with the audit, you would have closed it due to low quality?

Comment: @yivi What can you say about the answer of CodeCaster? He is a 130k user and he thinks the answer should not have been deleted, and he is probably more familiar with the standards than either of us. I agreee that editing would have been the best option, but the post is still not valid for an audit. (In my last comment I asked about something you have answered by now).

Comment: Quote from my post: "I'd appreciate if you could explain me how to detect these kinds of answers in audits and why they are suitable" If the answer should not have been deleted, then it is not a good audit. Therefore it answers my question.

Comment: Lets assume that you are right. When someone fails that audit, the reviewer thinks it is because the person made some asumptions (needs clarification->comment). However, the real reason is nowhere close. It would be better to at least edit/replace that comment with one that actually addresses the issue. Otherwise it just messes with new people who would unreasonably flag similar answers, because that's what this audit teaches them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers)

Comment: @gnat no, the answer is new. No other answer states the same solution.

Comment: @yivi I don't know who actually uses that FAQ or reads it after editing, but it's unreadable. Can you explain what OP should have done in the case when they opened the question in a new tab, saw the answer didn't exist anymore, believed it doesn't have any obvious editing opportunities _and_ adds something that the existing answers don't address? If you need a four page flowchart to review a post that was incorrectly flagged and the only easy way out is to skip (keeping a good answer deleted), there's something wrong with the flowchart _and_ the reviewing system, not to mention the flaggers.

Comment: @CodeCaster that it differs from prior answers doesn't make it OK (compare for example to top answer there, it is just so much better). I also have a feeling that you think it's a LQ queue audit, where reviewers choose whether to delete or keep - please note it is not. This is LA audit and reviewer picked No Action Needed, thus [depriving new user opportunity to improve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601). Audit failure was legit

Comment: @gnat I'd just like to point out that the explanation for the audit states that it is not an answer, which is just not true. yivi convinced me that the 'no action needed' was not the good choice and that it should have been edited - however the current explanation is really misleading, and I think (if the post remains an audit) that part should be edited.

Comment: @gnat Visual Studio debugger issues can have many entirely different causes, this answer added a new one that wasn't mentioned. Doesn't matter that answers describing different causes were formatted better . Deleting a useful answer deprived many more visitors of helpful information, just because the poster _could_ have used quotes around the setting name or added a screenshot.

Comment: I'm not sure if "requires editing" was an option for this audit, but the result would be the same: a useful answer got deleted.

Comment: @CodeCaster There is no 'requires author/community edit' button in that queue, but I could've edited the post directly and used the 'I'm done' button afterwards.

Comment: However, if I give it a bit more thought, editing would go against the faq. It states that not-an-answer posts must be flagged and not edited. If we accept the reasoning behind the audit, editing would not be the correct action - even if the machine accepts it. This just makes the audit more questionable.

Comment: @tibetiroka this was not an explanation for the audit but somewhat misguided and not very relevant comment. Explanation for the audit is displayed to reviewer at the moment of failure and its text is much different (and by the way this post shouldn't have been treated as not-an-answer and [audit didn't require you to do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601))

Comment: @gnat To my knowledge, the explanation is generated from the flag used, which was incorrect. About the second part of your comment, I did say that I'd probably pass the audit, but it doesn't justify the action. If it is NAA, then editing is not the solution. If it is low-quality, then mark it as so or edit it, and don't flag it as NAA.

Comment: I never argued it was NAA. Actually, I say the opposite. And that the objective of the queue is not simply to detect NAA.

Comment: you weren't attentive, otherwise you'd notice that comment is generated from a [different review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27998891) and that it is not necessarily relevant to review you are doing. As a more general rule, it is better to abstain of blindly trusting comments generated by a system as these may be made by mistake. Reviewers are supposed to use their own, independent judgement of the *post* and not just support or oppose other reviewers

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen a clear explanation of what that 'from review' actually means, it is not mentioned in the [wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) linked by yivi. Thank you for explaining that. I now understand *why* it is wrong (if it is wrong), but that doesn't make it any better for future reviewers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This:

> I had this error after using the checkbox to make single instance application in the program properties section. It was strange that it didn't throw an error before this. The program would crash every time suddenly on startup and not break on a line that showed I didn't have a code error. After unchecking the make single instance application the program fired right up.

Is an answer and should not have been deleted. Sure, it could be edited to be made more clear, but it answers the question: for them unchecking the "Make single instance application" checkbox makes the problem go away.

I guess that that checkbox injects some code in the executable, causing Visual Studio to give the error about not being able to find the source file for said code.

Perhaps the reviewers stopped reading after "I had this error" and thought it was a "me too" answer.

Sure, the answer could use some editing, but which answer doesn't? That doesn't make this a bad answer. I've done my due diligence and edited it.

Comment: I tend to agree. It's not great, but it's also not clear it's a retread if it is. I undeleted it and unsuspended @tibetroka

Answer (score 4):

If you had encountered this post in the "Low quality post" queue (from where it was originally deleted) , I would have understood if you had clicked "Looks OK". I would have preferred that you clicked "edit" to at least fix some spelling issues and polish the answer a bit, but I can certainly get on board with the idea that it doesn't qualify as "not an answer".

Alas, you found the audit the "late answers" queue. There the expectations are different. This queue is not simply to decide is something needs to be deleted or not. It's more complex and subtle queue which very often benefits from subject matter expertise to correctly review items. As opposed to the LQP queue, the whole post interface is enabled, even voting buttons.

To find these audits, the best way is to rely in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) for the LA/FP queues. While it may look long and intimidating at first, after following only once or twice, it becomes very easy to internalize the ideas of the guide.

For example for this answer:

> I had this error after using the checkbox to make single instance application in the program properties section. It was strange that it didn't throw an error before this. The program would crash every time suddenly on startup and not break on a line that showed I didn't have a code error. After unchecking the make single instance application the program fired right up.

The answer seems quite basic and lacking details. Since it's in the Late Answers review queue, this point of the guidance seems appropriate:

> Seems relatively trite and not particularly thorough, especially if there are a number of other answers and the question is not new:
>
> - Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if a substantially earlier answer already said everything this does

This would have revealed that the answer had been deleted, and thus was an audit. That the answer had been deleted (correctly or incorrectly) is irrelevant. This was the first correct thing to do in this queue for a post like this: open the question and check the other answers.

Additionally, even if the answer had not been deleted, saying it required **no action** was wrong, because the answer certainly would benefit from some third and first party edits.

First, grammar and spelling. Since it's referring to an graphical IDE, a screen-shot showing where this check-box exists wouldn't go amiss. Put the option name between quotes, for clarity. (Again, remember this is the LA queue, we are going for polish, not simply detecting what to delete).

Also there are parts of the answer that are hard to understand. The answer says "I had this error", but then goes on to describe **completely different** errors than the ones described on the question. Weird. At the very minimum deserving a comment, right?

When you click in "No Action Needed" you are saying "take this item from the queue, input is not required from other users".

One can reasonably disagree with the answer deletion (I wouldn't have flagged it for deletion myself) but that would still not make it a post that didn't require additional love from reviewers.

As an audit, worked perfectly, because it tested that you were paying attention to all the appropriate things for the queue, not simply if it was a answer worth deleting or not.

Doing any of the following actions (which were appropriate for this review-item) would have revealed/passed the audit:

- Open the question to check the other answers (required for an answer like this)
- Edit (needed fixes)
- Comment (needs details)

Even voting, which is also a good thing to do (either up or down, according to your own personal judgement) in this queue. And finally, if all those things were too much, skipping is the healthier choice.