# Flag declined for plagiarized content. Why?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, plagiarism

I flagged this answer in this state [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76072342/1) for plagiarized content from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68989453/965146), but my flag was declined with this reason:

> Declined - yes, it's copied, but the poster said "The code written
> below didn't work". they aren't trying to get credit for it or
> otherwise pass it off as their own work

Yes, the declined reason was justified after the edit, but I flagged that before the edit. What I am missing here for plagiarized flags?

Comment: Relevant MSE post: [Flag declined after an edit. How can we fix this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116764/flag-declined-after-an-edit-how-can-we-fix-this)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I declined it. The situation is a bit strange.

When two "Plagiarized content" flags are raised on the same post the moderator UI shows only the first one. I don't yet know to what extent this can be considered a bug and what exact circumstances may cause this.

So, your flag was not the one I saw in the moderator UI because someone else (let's call them User100) had flagged the same post with the same alleged source before you. The wording used in *their flag* referred to a comment that User100 themselves had posted under that answer. However the comment was deleted by another moderator at an earlier time.

So when I looked at the flag raised by User100, and without the context of the then-deleted comment, the text read to me as referring to the later versions of the post. *I definitely omitted to check the post timeline and the deleted comments*, as by then the resolution of that flag seemed clear-cut enough to me.

I then declined *the other user's flag* with the text you quoted in your question, and the system declined your flag together with theirs with the same text.

So basically you got the decline message that I meant for the other user. Given how the entire flag handling unfolded, I'm inclined to think that the current plagiarism flag UX for moderators needs improvement.

---

With that said, **both** flags weren't great. The post in its first revision was indeed just a poorly-formatted copy-paste of a couple lines from the other post but it would've been perhaps more appropriate to flag it as "In need of moderator intervention" and get it deleted as a non-obvious NAA or as a late retread, instead of plagiarism. Such short code-only copied answers from new users in many cases are just the outcome of them wanting to say "Thank you", or some other non-answer reply, and not knowing how the site works. Personally, I would almost surely mark such a plagiarism flag helpful (unless I fail to see context like in this case) but it's not necessary to assume ill intent, as a plagiarism flag implies.

---

**Update**: the issue described in this post has been brought to the attention of Staff as a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: Strange situation allowed mod to declined flag, got it. Any way thanks for declined.

Comment: @4b0 yeah, a part of it is my fault too, I didn’t double-check all the details I could double-check

Comment: Thanks for reply and honest answer. I know mods are great :) . Thanks or serving community.

Comment: What is meant by *"a late [retread](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retread#Noun)"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen late answers that repeat (or rehash or retread) what other answers to the same question have already said without adding anything new. We usually delete these as “late retreads”.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I guess this word usage is based on this old canonical discussion: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255571/839601)

Comment: Ah yes, it is [the second meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retread#Noun_2).