# Can/Should anything be done about popular, accepted and clearly-wrong answers?

Tags: discussion

I have come across a few (mostly older) questions that have highly-upvoted, accepted answers that are objectively wrong.

Example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424436/141172

I suppose the theory is that downvotes of the accepted answer plus upvotes of a correct answer will allow the cream to rise to the top.  That seems not to happen, particularly with older answers (probably because answers attracted many more votes in the early days).

With the older answers, the chances are less that the OP or author of the accepted answer are still active members.

Can or should anything be done to increase visibility of the correct answer and/or decrease visibility of the incorrect, accepted answer beyond up/down voting?

---

I first noticed this particular question around 6 months ago.  I came across it again today, and the dominance of the objectively wrong answer had not changed.  I did up/down vote as appropriate, and upvoted a spot-on comment about the answers.

---

The difference in average vote quantities past and present has emerged as a factor in the discussion of this question.  That reminded me of one of my answers.

[How to check for file lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock)

In this case, the accepted answer was probably right *at the time the question was asked*.  My answer came much later and is right *in the present* (the old answer is no longer optimal).

The original accepted answer with 87 net upvotes is from 2008.  My answer is 6 months old, and has 20 upvotes, or about 25% as many as the accepted answer.  Time is working... my answer garners a steady stream of upvotes, and should be on par with the accepted answer (though below a different, older answer) in 18 months at the current rate.

This is possibly a question that would benefit from my suggestion to highlight questions where one or more new answers are gaining upvotes significantly faster than an older, accepted answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265728/141172

Comment: You can downvote such answers. Add a comment if you like. **That's it**. And this actually *does work*, don't distrust time so much.

Comment: I did, and I upvoted a spot-on comment around 6 months back when I first discovered the question.  I searched for it again today because I forgot the answer, and saw that the correct answer was still unaccepted and with 1/4 the votes of the wrong answer.  I have seen that type of thing several times, though other examples escape me at the moment.

Comment: Your specific example is not that highly voted, really. It evidently is either a more obscure corner (not many people actually know the answer) or the subject is otherwise not attracting much traffic. 45 up, 4 down after almost 5 years is really not that much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Which would mean that time is unlikely to rectify the incorrect answer.  Those that do need/care about a correct answer will have to wait a very long time for the correct answer to rise to the top.

Comment: I cannot judge here how incorrect the accepted answer *is*. This is why there is voting; hopefully those that do know vote. But we cannot go by the say-so of a few to indicate that the post is entirely wrong and should be de-emphasised.

Comment: Interesting that two comments on the accepted answer indicate that it worked for them. Meanwhile, the next answer is superbrief, approaching link-only. I think those contribute further to this being a corner case.

Comment: In other words: How do we know you are right and the accepted answer is indeed incorrect? There are 45 upvotes on that answer indicating people found it helpful. There currently is no other mechanism other than voting to determine the helpfulness of an answer. Commenting helps, especially with a comment that can explain clearly how the specific answer is wrong.

Comment: @EricJ.: and the answer with +10 is, frankly, very thin on the ground. It also appears that for some circumstances, at least, the answer is reported to work. I cannot validate this, no experience in the tools whatsoever. In summary, it appears that the specific case you picked is not cut and dry, and the competing answer is not of great quality either. Write a better answer, one that explains what to do, why to do it like that and refuting the accepted answer clearly and with documentation. Then see if it doesn't eventually garner more upvotes.

Comment: Please leave a more constructive comment than "Such a highly upvoted and accepted answer that is clearly wrong." People are less likely to try to fix a highly-upvoted and accepted answer if you don't explain *what* is wrong with it.

Comment: @SamIam: If that's a dupe, it needs a title change.  Wrong answers and bad questions are entirely different beasts.

Comment: @BenVoigt The urge to copy my answer out of that question and post it here was too strong for me to not mark this as a duplicate

Comment: @SamIam: I think if you feel the same way about answers, you should add an answer to this question.  It wouldn't be a direct copy-paste, quite a bit of rework is needed.  And you can start with "I've already expressed my opinion about upvoted bad questions (link); I feel similar about accepted bad answers"

Comment: Please don't close as a dupe of that question, since it is about QUESTIONS, not anwers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `And this actually does work, don't distrust time so much.` -> I think we live in different time dimensions then. More often than not, it is nearly impossible to get bad answers out of their highly upvotes state. I cannot even get more than 1-2 downvotes usually for a clearly link-only, but very old and hence upvoted answer, let alone bad posts.

Comment: @FinalContest: then the post was *useful to some*. Convince a posse in a chat room that the answer is bad then to help adjust the vote tally. Make sure there is a comment on the post *clearly* explaining why the answer is wrong. Make sure there is a *correct answer* there too so people can upvote that one to replace the bad answer.

Comment: Just made my civic duty, downvoted and upvoted the answers ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If you need to "convince a posse in chat", _that is already the sign of something broken, isn't it?_ I appreciate your advice and I think they work on a theoretical level, but not in the _practice_. I would be happy if it did. I have done all that before, and oftentimes this had not put me ahead. Now, you could say that I am wrong about the judgement, and I would even consider it being true if other core contributors of the project would not agree with me. They are not on Stack Overflow, partially because of bad answers and poor questions.

Comment: @FinalContest: What other solutions do you propose? Because it **requires** a community consensus that a given answer is bad. You cannot just point at an answer, say *that is a bad answer and should go away*, and have it be so *just by your say-so*. If you are looking at a bad answer that is upvoted because the community of experts is not participating, then you have a problem with that community. If they don't care about the quality, then **there is nothing we can do**.

Comment: @FinalContest: And that's the problem with the example Eric here presented: It is **not** cut and dry that the answer is wrong or bad. There is also no decent competing answer, no clear comments explaining how the answer is bad, etc. That's a failure on the part of the experts to communicate why the answer is bad, not a failure on how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: the first step would be people becoming objective and not subjective with full of revenge around. This is a community issue and it is the responsibility of Mr. Heyer. I would also instantly remove the option of no reasoning for downvotes. These would be such enormous step ahead attracting further experts to contribute. I would also introduce weighted vote for experts, starting with -2 with golden badge. I would also consider a queue/notification for gold badge holders to review such answers that are flagged by other gold badge holders. Plenty of ways to approach it...

Comment: @FinalContest: I don't follow you. Are you saying that anonymous voting is keeping the experts away? You are very much wrong there. That subject has been discussed to death and is not going to change, btw. I have *no idea* who Mr. Heyer is, in this context, either.

Comment: Distrusting time or not... At least it seems the meta-effect can be trusted ;-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I edited the competing answer to make it better than a link, and added a better comment.  The purpose of my question is not to discuss this particular question in great detail, but to discuss the category of questions where the accepted answer has many upvotes (likely due to older answers simply having received many more votes in general).  Perhaps I could have found a better example.

Comment: As @Robert suggests, the "steady stream of upvotes" you're seeing may be due to the [Meta Effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). It could very well trail off when this post is no longer on the front page.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: The last upvote for the answer in my update is July 9th.  Not sure about the answer I originally pointed out, as it is not from me.

Comment: @FinalContest, check the [first example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420390/dont-stop-debugger-at-that-exception-when-its-thrown-and-caught/1424436#1424436). The accepted answer has received at least 17 downvotes since this question was asked. But of course, it might be a coincidence ;-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: @FinalContest: Seen that blog before.  `I did what many of the people whose questions I answered (and got points for) should have done for themselves: I saw a simple Java question, hit Google, read briefly, then synthesized an original answer.` http://xkcd.com/810/

Comment: @EricJ.: stay tunned... my blog post is upcoming ;>

Comment: Let's see ..... obviously false popular answers .... there's religion, Fox News, and the myths about nutritional supplements. Can anything be done about them?

Comment: @BondedDust: Rupert Murdock could do something about FoxNews.  He elects not to.  We are in a position to continually improve on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Another example of an answer with a lot more points than the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668068/ruby-how-to-signal-not-implemented-yet except that in this case, both answers were the same day as the question, and yet it still looks like the OP took the first answer he saw and moved on.  The problem may often have to do with the OP just not being so active on the site/not considering it a high enough priority to maintain SO--after all, he got the answer he needed already.

Comment: If there are two right answers, I don't see any problem.  If the system highlights an answer that was never or is no longer correct, that is a problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No it doesn't work a lot of the time. Obviously it doesn't work. If it worked then there wouldn't be upvoted and accepted answers that are incorrect, yet there are many.

Answer (score 16):

Wikipedia flags articles that may be biased or incomplete, so that the user knows to pay special attention to the quality.  I would not suggest that we introduce editorial flags, but perhaps we could flag a question if one or more significantly newer answers are being upvoted at a much higher rate than an older, accepted answer, e.g.

*The best answer may have changed.  Newer answers are receiving significantly more upvotes than the accepted answer.*

Comment: If you feel bold, you could just *edit* this into the answer (indented in a quote box, terminated by a horizontal line) - as it was done with duplicate questions in the old days.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255574/829571 - you can add a comment pointing out what the problem is and edit the question by adding a short sentence at the top linking to the comment.

Comment: If you do this, [try to be objective](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3868314/revisions) @Bergi - see also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer

Comment: @Shog9: Sure, that's not what I meant to be done. Also I'd do it only when the answer was outdated, *completely* wrong, and still accepted on a popular question. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16096872/1048572) might be a viable candidate, see my comments on the high-voted answers (one of which was fixed).

Answer (score 6):

Many a times it happens that old answers are of no use anymore or incorrect answers are accepted by the user who asked the question. Some users care to correct their answers whereas some don't.

The best you can do over here is

- Downvote the answer
- Explain why the answer is incorrect with a comment or upvote comments which you feel are pointing the mistakes in the answer
- Post a correct answer if you know

I would insist not to flag answers as *Not an answer*, as moderators tend to reject those flags because

[image]

You should flag an answer only if one of the below reason is sufficed....

- Thank you comment
- Posting a different question as an answer on other question
- Posting a comment as an answer
- Replying to an answer by posting another answer

Comment: This is so funny how completely the same questions get fate. I asked the same question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256711/what-to-do-with-old-highvoted-answers-which-are-wrong and it was closed right away. Also your approach sounds strange to me: SO has a goal of providing good quality answers to programming questions (at least this is my understanding of the goal). And here it looks like people with correct answers have to go through a lot of problems to get rid of the wrong answer. If the answer is wrong, why not to remove it?

Comment: It sounds rediculous that out of big amount of SO moderators we can not find an expert who can tell "wow this does not make any sense/outdated/wrong". Lets remove it to reduce confusion for further readers. Instead of it community has just to wait for months so that correct answer will get more upvotes.

Comment: With regard to the last point, if someone posts an answer which is almost complete, but leaves out some important information, is there anything wrong with saying "Mr. Smith's answer will work reliably to create some kinds of objects, but it may randomly fail if used to create a Fizglub. If you need to create a Fizglub, then it will be necessary to Woogle the Fnorble first as shown below."  If Mr. Smith already stated 90% of what a reader would need to know, there's no point in repeating it; on the other hand, the remaining material may be more "answer" than "comment".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Treat it the exact same way that you would treat a brand new answer with no votes at all. Downvote if you think it's wrong, and flag it if you think it's not an answer or otherwise flaggable, just like you would were it new.

And if the answer remains upvoted, and you can't convince a moderator to remove it, then you're just going to have to live with the fact that you're not the sole decider of correctness around here, and that more people disagree with you about the answer than agree with you.

Comment: The real problem is that older answers gained a lot more attention than is generally the case now.  It takes a very long time for the surge of interest in an old answer to be overcome by newer answers.  When the accepted answer is incorrect, or only correct under narrow circumstances, that is bad for the community overall.

Comment: @EricJ.  Maybe the answer isn't quite so objectively incorrect as you believe it to be, especially considering that some of the comments under it actually say that it worked for them.

Comment: Don't flag it. The flag will likely get declined. Downvote it and add a comment that it is no longer accurate.

Comment: @staticx I did not just say to flag it.  I sad **"flag it if...**".  I was trying to write an answer for the abstract.  It wouldn't be appropriate to flag the specific example in the OP, but sometimes it is appropriate to flag.

Answer (score -1):

We could maybe have an additional sorting mode that weighs votes with the time that has passed since casting the vote, effectively overweighing newer votes. This might increase the significance of the score in all cases where newer evaluation are more likely to give a better opinion.

Alternatively one could additionally display a trend (little arrows or timelines) that give a hint about slope of the score lately.

Otherwise I trust in SO self correction abilities.

> What basis is there for expecting newer votes to be significantly more
>   useful than older votes?

The basis is twofold:

- For questions that depend on technology development (different solutions for different version, newer paradigms, more efficient algorithms, better tools and software) like web technologies over time the notion what the best answer is will shift. This is especially true for some answers but not for all.
- With more answers being posted or answers getting edited and improved the notion of what the best answer is can change. This applies to all answers.

Comment: What basis is there for expecting newer votes to be significantly more useful than older votes?

Comment: @AirThomas Very good question which should have been included earlier. There are two reasons. I added them to the answer.