# How can this question's incorrect answer get changed?

Tags: discussion

This question: [A programming language designed to be testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371268/a-programming-language-designed-to-be-testable)

has a very outdated accepted answer. The language cited as an answer (Noop) is dead: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/noop/V0-3rnIyLgA

Alternatively, there is a new answer at the very bottom pointing to Wake which claims to be Noop's rebirth: http://mikedrivendevelopment.blogspot.com/2014/07/from-ashes-of-googles-noop-comes.html

Acknowledgement: As the creator of Wake I am biased. I do not want a false answer to this question circling around, and have subsequent "duplicate questions" get rejected. I think having Wake up there would be important to Wake's publicity (we still get some hits from that URL, even though my answer is buried.)

Is there a standard way to update questions like these where the answer is outdated?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265646/can-should-anything-be-done-about-popular-accepted-and-clearly-wrong-answers

Comment: Thank you, there are great answers in here. I wish I could enact some of them (for instance, editing the accepted answer to say its dead). However I don't have the reputation and it would be a bad idea given I am not an objective source.

Comment: Well, I followed @Servy's answer and close voted. It wil not take long for that question to be gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is primarily opinion based and should be closed as such.  The problems you've brought up are among the reasons why these types of questions don't belong on the site in the first place.

Comment: I can see how it would relate to "favorite off-site resource".

Comment: I wouldn't say this is opinion based. Many of the cited languages do not have explicit statements from their creators saying they were "designed for unit testing." Those are added as a matter of opinion. However, there are two answers where the language creators did indeed publicly state testability as a design goal. One of those is the accepted answer, the other is at the bottom, and the accepted answer is a canceled project. Given there is some evidence to support my claims, is there really no value in attempting to reflect the evidence in the question?

Comment: @MikeFairhurst Reading through the question it is very clearly full of questions asking for opinions: "Do you agree with the statement that dynamic programming languages make writing tests easier?" "Or if you prefer twisting the question a bit, what imperative programming is bad practice or unnecessary to ensure testability?" "s there a programming language that [...] exhibit[s] very good properties in terms of testability?"  All of these things are asking for *opinions*.

Comment: You are right -- I was overly attached to the overall premise and ignored the rest. The question "Is there a programming language that is testable by design" has an absolute answer, but there are countless vague followup questions. I take my objectivity statement back (how could I choose what the "intended" question is?)

Perhaps the right solution would be to ask the same question in an objective form anew, and share my answer Q&A style?

Comment: Even that remaining question is still not an appropriate SO question.  It's a list question.  It has different problems, but still doesn't belong here.