# Should we have a "test the answer before accepting it" warning balloon for new users?

Tags: feature-request

We've more or less [come to a consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285885/2825369) that the poster of a question should verify that an answer actually solves the problem before formally marking it as the answer. However, new users may assume that an answer is the definitive word of an expert upon seeing anything at all, and then accept it without testing it, possibly to then vanish forever and **leave a wrong answer as accepted**.

We do have the "Populist" badge, which creates an incentive to answer even if there's a low-score accepted answer, but the accepted answer is always shown on top (unless it's by the OP). There has been [an initiative to change this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283456/2825369).

I propose that **a little balloon be shown** when a new user (such that it's their first or maybe even second time asking a question) clicks the check mark to accept an answer. The balloon would ask them to first test the answer before accepting it. To accept and confirm that it has been tested, the user would just click the hollow check again, and the balloon would vanish. (That behavior would be somehow indicated in the text.) It might also be worth linking to a relevant FAQ article, especially if the user does not have the "Informed" badge.

Possibly related: [what to do about wrong answers that are accepted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265646/2825369) and [why can't an answer be accepted in the first 15 minutes of a question's existence?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250132/2825369)

Comment: You can't earn the Populist badge over a low score answer.  You have to earn the Populist badge over an answer with at least +11 score, like [a Jon Skeet answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist?userid=2792531).

Comment: If there was to be a balloon, I would prefer one on posting that says 'Please ensure you include the details of your own debugging and what you found out'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm extraordinarily concerned with this suggestion.

If I had a dime for every time I posted a solution that *actually* solves the problem and eliminates the actual problem asked about only to get a comment that looks something like this:

> Okay, that works now, but this piece of code 5 lines later that wasn't even in the original question is broken with [error description].  How do I fix that?

... if I had a dime every time I heard that, I wouldn't even have a job any more.  I'd just answer questions posted by people with less than 1,000 reputation for a living.

This suggestion essentially encourages "chameleon" questions and "your code is in another castle" questions.  New users wouldn't mark an answer as accepted until their app is ready to ship for release.

---

Expanding on this, there are other problems too.

First of all, the bubble won't even always make sense.  Sometimes the question isn't even about how to fix up code.  Sometimes the question is a "why" question.  Consider [the most upvoted question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array), how would the "make sure it works before accepting" bubble work with this question and its answers?

Moreover, how about the inevitable and common case where the user does a zero-effort paste of their broken code, and the astute answerer, wishing to post an answer as non-specific to the original question as possible, while still answering the actual question?  The answerer won't necessarily use the same variable names or method names or anything like this.  Or the answerer explains how to do part of the problem in plain-English (perhaps something set up in an interface builder or visual designer), and explains the other part with code.  The answerer only copies & pastes the code, now complains the compiler is complaining about variable names and such.  This sort of thing actually happens fairly regularly.

And finally, there's a set of questions which [Martin James' comment points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293584/should-we-have-a-test-the-answer-before-accepting-it-warning-balloon-for-new-u/293587#comment189943_293584).  These questions don't provide enough detail to actually answer at the level of taking the question from not working to working.  But the question is clear enough what the problem is, and any answer can be quite clear on what the problem is an how to solve it as a general rule.  And actually, are these sorts of answers better?  Aren't the answers that teach the programmer how to debug better than the ones that just debug for him?

> Give a programmer a bug fix, he'll return tomorrow asking for another bug fix.  Teach a programmer to debug, and it'll be at least a week before he's back asking for more help.

---

And finally, [as I've pointed out before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291533/2792531), the accepted answer doesn't really matter *that* much.  Any question that continues to be useful to anyone besides the original person who posted the question will eventually have [its answers voted to correct levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498158/intercept-obj-c-delegate-messages-within-a-subclass).

Comment: Pfft.  I'd only need a penny.  But that counts both in-person *and* on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For me, in-person is more like "Now, when you work on Task X, keep in mind you won't by able to do Y because Z," and inevetably, "While working on task X, I ran into errors/problems A, B, C while trying to do Y."

Answer (score 9):

Honestly, I feel like they're shooting *themselves* in the foot for blindly coping and pasting a solution they found on the Internet, and while I strive for absolute accuracy when answer questions, I have no qualms about handing them their own instrument of doom.

Common sense and programming experience should temper a person's desire to want to just copy and paste code they found into their project, but if it doesn't, there's *very little* I feel that we could do to get them to realize the potential danger of doing so...until it hurts them greatly.

Comment: I think the real issue is when others look at the page afterwords and may now consider an incorrect answer as useful.

Comment: I would hope that a user looking for advice on a problem would take into account if it's been accepted, how many upvotes it has, and do their own investigative research to figure out if it'd be viable or correct for themselves.  Otherwise we're right back in the copy-and-paste loop.

Comment: It's probably only best to take into account whether it has been accepted if the asker appears to have a very good idea what they are talking about. Not always the case.