# Do we want single, complete answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, answer-quality, quality-improvement

Today I needed to find the version of a JAR file and I came across the question [How to check the version of a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834794/how-to-check-the-version-of-jar-file)

I found what I needed (thanks for that) and I actually needed three answers to solve my issue, which are

1. [info about decompressing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834843/4136325)
2. [info about the file name I'm looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606771/4136325)
3. [info on how to interpret the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436139/4136325)

Is that expected / wanted by Stack Overflow? Wouldn't it be better to create a (still short) single answer that would cover all details?

---

***Potential summary answer***

1. Decompress the JAR file (which is a ZIP file internally)
2. look for the manifest file (`META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`)
3. Look for a line with `Implementation-Version`. Not always a version is specified. (Do not look for `Manifest-Version`, which is the version of the MF file format).

---

I understand that several people have contributed to finally solve my problem. All of them deserve recognition and reputation.

However, from a *system* point of view, a single answer covering all the points would IMHO fit the intended Q&A style of Stack Overflow much more.

How should I handle such a situation? As you can see, I have edited [the highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834843/4136325) to include the path, before I noticed the next answer mentioning exactly that missing part, even stating

> Just to complete the above answer.

That again makes me think the answer should have been an edit, but of course an edit would not have given 100 reputation points, even if it might be worth those 100 points.

After reading the [third part of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436139/4136325), I was even tempted to edit again, but instead I ask this Meta question first.

**Are we (am I) encouraged to merge several partial answers into one more complete / better answer?** If so, how shall this be done? Edit the highest voted answer?

I don't want to create a new answer, since that's like the [joke about standards (XKCD)](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: Probably a feature request: Could we somehow merge answers and still give reputation to every contributor when upvoted?

Comment: The question would probably be closed as too broad nowadays. We want questions addressing a particular and specific problem, that can be solved in a single answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The JAR version question too broad? There are not so many ways of getting the version out of it, are there? And my 3 step proposal would make a nice single answer. (Leaving aside the quite special MD5 answer, which is interesting, but very special and helpful in a few cases only)

Comment: Considder a [self-answered Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188), citing the originals; see also these [programmatic approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2198525/230513).

Comment: @trashgod: and then flag the originals as duplicate?

Comment: @Thomas: I'd certainly add a comment to the original linking to your more narrowly focused Q&A.

Comment: (my first contrib to meta so please forgive me): As you say there are 2 views: The contributors who supplied the answers; three people contributed their $0.02 to provide a complete picture. And the system, in which a single answer might be better.  I feel the system's point of view should be deemed *less* important. Yes, a single complete answer might be better for the system... But people are people. They have egos. They feel good when they contribute. Messing with their answers does not help this. There are so many questions that we need the hive mind. So the contributors are most important!

Comment: You could pick the most-nearly-complete answer and leave a comment explaining what info needs to be added to make the answer complete; if the answerer does not make the appropriate edit, you should consider writing your own comprehensive answer. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287692/1858225) for a somewhat similar situation.

Comment: That is why I am encouraging this [proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/1577396).

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 are not distinct. Any ZIP or JAR viewer will accomplish them both, and will also accomplish 3 actually.

Comment: Even putting all the answers together, the result is sub-optimal: there's lot of reinventing functionality which the standard library provides. If you have some versioned jars to test with then I suggest you put together some sample code with `java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest()` and the suitable methods of `java.util.jar.Manifest` and post it as a new answer.

Comment: @Thomas at this point, the reputation would remain even if the answers are deleted. Reputation changes older than six months on answers is permanent.

Comment: Why you needed 3 answers to find what is in the Java documentation is beyond me... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html. I actually agree with @πάντα ῥεῖ in some sense. The question might not be closed for being too broad but it would be closed due to a complete lack of effort

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing: Nothing against the Java documentation here, it's quite good. But if StackOverflow is the first (Google) search hit, then it should IMHO provide at least good information.

Comment: Love your idea of merging and combining rep @Thomas - I'd upvote that feature request on meta :)

Comment: Not necessarily.  Do most problems only have a single solution?  Is a long answer that discusses multiple independent solutions better than a concise answer that focuses on a single solution?  Where there are multiple alternative solutions, it's more useful for them to be enumerated separately.  Although that _is_ different than the case of a "just to complete the above..." answer.

Comment: FWIW, I would have put my part of the answer (step 3 in the summary above) as comment on Vivek's answer, with the intent that answer be edited to clarify this, except at the time I did not have enough reputation to post comments so SO made me post a whole new answer. I didn't duplicate the already answered portion (steps 1 & 2) as I didn't want to be considered "copying" someone else's work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Yes

Editing an existing answer is good but in this specific case it seems like the 'best' thing would be to add another answer that combines all of the relevant points.

If the best existing answer is missing a *detail* then it would be most helpful to other users to simply add the missing detail (if you have edit privileges) or include it a comment.

But if you're combining multiple answers or adding more than a single detail there's no reason why you can't add your own answer to consolidate all of the relevant info.

And, IMHO, multiple answers with the same content can still be useful as there are sometimes many ways of expressing or representing a point or multiple ways to solve a problem.

Also, [as Jessica Pennell points out in their answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305716/173497), you should always cite your sources, especially if they're other Stack Overflow questions or answers.

Comment: I'd have to agree to this. It sounds like the best solution. I think editing answers with many points is not so nice. It's like changing a few lines in a novel by a great author; you just don't do that. Even if the edits are in fact improving it.

Comment: +1 for citing that you should cite source :)

Comment: I'd say that if an answer is almost a copy paste of a few answers (mostly non-original content), it should be community-wiki.

Comment: @Justin: I don't care, personally. It takes time and editing work to combine multiple answers properly, just selecting the right morsels requires effort for example.

Comment: [we want *complete* answers; it doesn't mean that each question should have a *single* answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305720/4279)

Comment: Totally agree; I have done this myself in the past. Reputation and / or making sure it's all divided up fairly must be a secondary consideration to the primary consideration, which is to have excellent answers. There is potential for abuse but that should be dealt with separately if / when it happens.

Comment: If I understand Community Wiki correctly, this is pretty much exactly what it's for.

Comment: @DavidWallace [It seems like Community Wiki is (now) intended for questions that one user **cannot** (reasonably?) create a single comprehensive answer.](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) This does not seem to fit that criteria. And maybe an answer *warranting* being Community Wiki is evidence that the question is too broad.

Answer (score 28):

I realize I'm newer here. That said whenever I answer a question on any Q&A site where I relied on other answers to formulate my own, I provide links to the other answers in my own answer. I always thumbs up (or whatever the equivalent on the particular Q&A site I happen to be on is) the source answers myself, and I've found this approach encourages others to do the same.

Stack Overflow allows you to answer your own questions. So there is nothing stopping you from proposing your question, and then answering your own questions, with links to all your sources, after upvoting the sources. Except possibly ethics, but I think it's a good idea that would increase the value of Stack Overflow and save people like me googling here a lot of time.

Also I think this approach is flexible enough to create usefully (typically singly, occasionally even doubly) linked lists of related questions with varying degrees of detail, making it very easy for someone with a particularly nasty or hard to even search for question to find the answer they really want.

Comment: Jeez – I totally dropped the ball by not mentioning that we should all cite our sources where possible. Not doing so is just bad manners.

Comment: @KennyEvitt: it is not just manners, look at the footer on every page on Stack Overflow: all user-contributed content is under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Answer (score 10):

I want to add something regarding the title of your question:

> Do we want single, complete answers?

I think we want *complete* answers, but that doesn't mean *single* answers.

An answer is complete if it solves the problem. The answers you found were not complete, so not as helpful as they could have been. The "system", as you called it, can't deal very well with solutions that need content from multiple answers; that's not its purpose.

The reason we have multiple answers is competiton. Given multiple answers - that all solve the problem - the users vote what answer presents the best solution, or presents the solution best. In an Ideal World™, you posting a new, complete answer (as Kenny [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305713/371191)) will make you rise to the top quickly, making your answer very visible.

Comment: Usually the first decent answer gets a lot of votes.  Having the OP accept it, even if there are better general-case answers, only makes things worse.  People vote up this already-high-voted and accepted answer, and by the time they notice a better answer later, it's too late to undo the upvote on the current top answer.  It takes a long time for a situation like that to reverse itself, and the best answer to finally get more votes.

Answer (score 1):

**In most situations yes**

**Situations when you are**
Reputation eager person will see an opportunity to gain reputation by merging the three answers into a new one. So yes, they are encouraged to merge the content. Thus making one complete answers.

When you are the person searching the answer, Yes you are since it makes better contents and also make it the most visible one. Thus you are saving time and effort for the next searching person and this makes you feel good about yourself.
People without privilege, simply comment to do the same. (Most people do this)

**Situation when you aren't**
Without edit privilege, it is sometime hard to do put the additional content in a comment because of the formatting limitation in comment. This precise situation do not encourage you to upgrade the answer. In this situation, you are encouraged to add another answered for readability purpose, but people act like it is annexed to the other answer to not steal the original answer.

Also, many reputation eager person will post the additional content in an new answer to obtain gain with their contribution. They could gain more reputation by including the other answer's content in their own, but they don't because they would feel like stealing other's content. Thus making them feel bad.

**So all in all,** 
those who added complementary answer were either reputation eager, or hadn't edit privilege and wanted to avoid messing with comment section. **In all cases, they wanted to preserve the right of the best author by supporting him. So are you by editing his answer to include theirs content.**

Comment: As @Jessica Pennell stated, citing in your edit would be very professional and good pratice.