# Is the table-flipping emoticon an appropriate way to critique an answer's use of a bad reference?

Tags: discussion, comments

I just came across a [really low-quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36340058/2788872) to an already answered, popular question. Aside from accounting for the fact that almost the entire answer is copied from the source linked within, there are two subjective problems with it:

1. it does not really answer the question at all (it is obnoxious of its contents),
2. it links to <strike>the cesspool</strike> w3schools, which IMO -- and other people's, I believe -- is bad practice.

With these in mind, I just couldn't resist commenting with this:

> (╯°□°）╯︵ [ɯoɔ˙slooɥɔsƐʍ]

Is this acceptable behavior here? While I do think it clearly explains the current state of affairs, it clearly breaks from the more mature and serious environment of SO. I'd be lying if I said I wasn't inclined towards a "no".

Comment: clearly explains the status? I honeslty can't get what you're hinting at by flipping the site... Leave a downvote on the answer if you think it's poor. THAT'S a clear message. Or write a non-equivocal comment explaining your points 1 & 2 here.

Comment: @Patrice _"I honeslty can't get what you're hinting at by flipping the site..."_ AFAIK, w3schools is discouraged from being linked to, thus the guy in the text is fed up with it and throws it away.

Comment: I don't remember us discouraging any sites (then again I do stay far from w3schools)... but yeah, make your point CLEAR, not with emojis or whatnot.

Comment: I deleted this question accidentally (for a moment). I don't even....

Comment: @Patrice: Oficially, SE doesn't discourage the use of any specific site. However, the JS community has no love for w3schools due to incomplete, inaccurate and simply wrong information, on there.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah I did a bit of research after I asked the question. I realize that now. In general though, I think we should make a clearer job of exposing that this is bad. What's wrong with a clear comment that'll explain that to the answer's OP, no matter his culture, level of familiarity with English, and (even worse) his level of knowledge on emojis....

Comment: The question is ... unwise (not exactly what I would call it, but calling the question stupid outright would be frowned upon), but the comment is fine.  It's not really constructive, but so is this comment.  And this question.  If you ask if you can leave a jerky comment, the answer is going to be no.  If you leave a jerky comment, it might get flagged as not constructive and removed, but who cares?  Everybody had their bit of fun.  Jeez, why did you have to go and ask this?  Ugh.

Comment: I would have literally no idea what you were trying to convey with that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it is not.

The comment, as quoted in this question, can be considered *"Not constructive"*.

Try to inform users why a certain site shouldn't be used, instead of just flipping it over. In this specific case, I added this comment:

> Please don't link to w3schools. The information on there is often incomplete, inaccurate, or plain wrong. Use sites like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) instead.

Something similar can be used for other sites that are of insufficient quality. But remember, be nice and be helpful!

Comment: on a somewhat related note, when you see something from w3schools, you might want to do the courtesy of making sure that the information there is actually bad information before you start criticizing it based solely on which website it happens to be posted on.

Comment: Imo, we should advice users about the _best_ resources out there. Regardless of the specific page they're looking at. w3schools is _far_ from the best resource. In the end, users looking at better resources -> better programmers -> better questions and answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus W3Schools often has more examples than MDN, which people find helpful. MDN is not a clear win in all cases. Perhaps MDN+SO Docs will be sufficient to eliminate the need for W3Schools, but we're not there yet.

Comment: Examples don't necessarily mean good documentation. The info on there is just as often incomplete.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I think the context here is not about recommendations of sites, but rather the comment left

Comment: I agree. Maybe this w3schools dicussion is better removed?

Comment: Fair enough, I get it and I agree: flipping tables is below standards here.

Answer (score 10):

When I see comment flags that require a moderator to intervene and I end up  purging all the comments or most of them (for various reasons - users having a go at each other/generally spiralling into mayhem), I leave a comment along the lines of:

**Moderator note:** please keep comments **constructive**, civil and for clarifying the post.

(I've highlighted **constructive** here).

Your comment wasn't constructive - nor particularly even amusing.

I've deleted that comment and I'd ask that you don't leave such comments in the future.

Sometimes it's all too easy to give in to wanting to give a snide remark, but just don't - it doesn't help anyone, it does nothing more than just make you look like a fool.

Comment: wonder if you noticed that answer discussed here was dumped at question having 170K views. Such questions are typically in the need of protection. A good dose of [Atwood's cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) wouldn't hurt either. Alternatively, we can just sit and wait until it gets polluted by 3 more answers that are bad enough to be deleted which will trigger automatic protection. (related: [Question with horrible answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255527/839601))

Comment: @gnat I was focusing on the context of this question and it's relation to the comment left - not the post itself. For the time being I've locked that Q as historical.

Comment: the way you handled comments makes good sense to me. And now that you complemented it with locking the question I literally have nothing to complain about :)

Comment: I appreciate your concise response. I suspected as much, and in the absence of clarification I would have advised the same -- this one slipped through, though. I had a thinking time picking _the_ answer, but I ended up going for the other one, mainly for its first line. Either way, thanks.

Comment: @gnat someone somewhere will find something to complain about at sometime :p

Comment: @JohnWhite I'm not looking for acceptance of an answer or not. It's just the way it is - I'm trusting that after asking this question you won't be leaving such comments again? Am I right?