# Clarification on declined flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Yesterday I flagged SoulReaper's answer on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033083/xampp-start-automatically-on-windows-7-startup/39727039#39727039) as being "Not an answer", simply because I felt it was rather a comment.

The explanation for the declined flag is that

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an
>   altogether wrong answer

This is in general true, but here I think it is difficult to consider it a wrong or inaccurate answer...

Comment: Done. Sorry, I forget to provide the link...

Comment: related: [Question with horrible answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255527/question-with-horrible-answers) (at 30K views question must be high in web searches, would be nice if someone protected it from garbage "answers" posted by passers by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* attempt to answer the question, so a 'Not an answer' flag is not warranted. Use the 'Very Low Quality' flag instead.

Comment: Ok, you're right. Will pay more attention next time. Thanks a lot for your prompt reply